Why not Past Perfect

I arrived at the airport in time to kiss Linda good-bye before the plane took off.

Why is Past Perfect never used  in such cases? One action clearly happens before the other, why not “had arrived”?

Americans tend not to use the past perfect if simple past will be understood similarly.

@Barmar that’s the thing, with this “in time” construction Brits use Past Simple only too.

You don't need to use past perfect if the order of events is obvious. Please search for similar questions.

The past perfect isn't required in this particular context. If the narrator was telling the story from the perspective of a later time, they might say "I remembered that I had arrived at the airport in time to kiss Linda goodbye before the plane took off."
